# Iterate through a nested python dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a JSON file that looks like this:

```json
{
    "returnCode": 200,
    "message": "OK",
    “people”: [
        {
            “details: {
                "first": “joe”,
                “last”: doe,
                “id”: 1234567,
            },
            “otheDetails”: {
                “employeeNum”: “0000111222”,
                “res”: “USA”,
                “address”: “123 main street”,
            },
            “moreDetails”: {
                “family”: “yes”,
                “siblings”: “no”,
                “home”: “USA”,
            },
        },
       {
            “details: {
                "first": “jane”,
                “last”: doe,
                “id”: 987654321,
            },
            “otheDetails”: {
                “employeeNum”: “222333444”,
                “res”: “UK”,
                “address”: “321 nottingham dr”,
            },
            “moreDetails”: {
                “family”: “yes”,
                “siblings”: “yes”,
                “home”: “UK,
            },
        }
```

This shows two entries, but really there are hundreds or more. I do not know the number of entries at the time the code is run.

My goal is to iterate through each entry and get the 'id' under "details". I load the JSON into a python dict named 'data' and am able to get the first 'id' by:

```
data['people'][0]['details']['id']
```

I can then get the second 'id' by incrementing the '0' to '1'. I know I can set i = 0 and then increment i, but since I do not know the number of entries, this does not work. Is there a better way?

Comment: `ids = [dct['details']['id'] for dct in data['people']]` should work, no? `data['people']` is a list, so you can do a list comprehension on it specifically.

Comment: thanks for the response. this gives me a key error on 'id' though. ids = [dct['details']['first'] for dct in data['people']] works on getting the first name, but for some reason doesn't work when i use 'id' or any other field under 'details'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dict.get` method in a list comprehension to avoid getting a KeyError on `id`. This way, you can fill dictionaries without `id`s with `None`:

```
ids = [dct['details'].get('id') for dct in data['people']]
```

If you still get KeyError, then that probably means some `dct`s in `data['people']` don't have `details` key. In that case, it might be better to wrap this exercise in `try/except`. You may also want to identify which `dct`s don't have `details` key, which can be gathered using `error_dct` list (which you can uncomment out from below).

```
ids = []
#error_dct = []
for dct in data['people']:
    try:
        ids.append(dct['details']['id'])
    except KeyError:
        ids.append(None)
        #error_dct.append(dct)
```

Output:

```
1234567
987654321
```

Answer (score 2):

Less pythonic then a list comprehension, but a simple for loop will work here.

You can first calculate the number of people in the `people` list and then loop over the list, pulling out each id at each iteration:

```
id_list = []

for i in range(len(data['people'])):
    id_list.append(data['people'][i]['details']['id'])
```